# How to call a function from functions.php with ajax?

Tags: php, functions, ajax, jquery, javascript

I'm wondering how can i call a function from functions.php and print it with Ajax in a specific place (woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button).

I know i can simply add my function in add_action like what i did below but i though that ajax is the way to go because my function output got cached (full page caching) so i though that ajax can be a solution for that issue.

```
<?php
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'hello_world', 10);
    function hello_world() 
      {
        $var1 = 'Hello World!';
        echo $var1;
        echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
      }
?>
```

I would appreciate if the answers was very simplified since i'm totally new to coding. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mean need to display the custom code your ajax add to cart button right? . add this below code your current active function.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'hello_world', 10);
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'hello_world', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'hello_world', 10);
function hello_world() {
$var1 = 'Hello World!';
echo $var1;
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my function is already placed in the add_action similar to what you mentioned but unfortunately the output got cached since I'm using W3 Total cache page caching so i though that calling that function via ajax can solve that issue and return the dynamic output of that function